# Looking for an in detail explanation of the Random Walk Over a Cliff Problem

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

On Puzzle Exchange I already found this answer great: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6431/8863

Currently I there are two steps I don't yet understand. For example the connectin between characteristic polynominals and recurrence relations.

I find this topic well researchable and study on my own.

However I cannot follow the reasoning:

> If we assume $p\neq\frac{1}{2}$, this polynomial has two distinct roots:
>   $$
> r=1,\hspace{1cm} r=\frac{p}{1-p}.
> $$
>   This means that $d(x)$ has the form
>   $$
> d(x)=c_1+c_2\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^x,
> $$

Where does the letter form come from? I see there are in fact both roots used. I guess the "full" form would be:
$ d(x) = c_1 r_1^x + c_2 r_2 ^x $, with $r_1, r_2$ being the just found roots. Is there a name for this step (+ proof!), coming from the roots of the characteristic polynominal to a closed form? I have just found:

http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC3/Bjorn1/node6.html

But sadly no proof provided :Z

Comment: An equivalent "game", for which you will find many references on the web is known under the name "Gambler's ruin"

Comment: You might try googling "solution of linear difference equations with constant coefficients".  Note that the word is "difference", NOT "differential".